# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться c этой ошибкой:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/юзер/data/www/сайт.ру/index.php on line 33

Вот 33 строка:

```
if (array_key_exists("p", $_GET) && in_array($_GET["p"], ["admin", "password-reset"])) {
```

Версия PHP 5.3.28

Comment: PHP какой версии?

Comment: Попробуйте `in_array($_GET["p"], array("admin", "password-reset")`

Comment: php 5.1-5.6, так написано на reg.ru

Comment: @JackWolf,  в PHP5.1 и PHP5.6 ваш код будет работать **по разному**. Без указания конкретной версии вам нельзя помочь (телепаты не в счет).

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, вот нашёл: 5.3.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP 5.3.x нет короткого синтаксиса для массивов. А значит, конструкция

```
["admin", "password-reset"]
```

не валидна.

Используйте вместо нее

```
array("admin", "password-reset")
```

**Для справки:**

Сокращенный синтаксис определения массивов появился только в [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: спасибо,решилось, но возникла ещё одна ошибка, попробую исправить..

Comment: хах, решил проблему, просто поменял php, но всё равно спасибо!